# Перенести данные из input в тег html через нажатие кнопки

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток!
Возник вопрос как перенести данные из input в тег html по нажатию кнопки save.
Есть код

```
  <div class="profile__info">
            <h1 class="profile__name">Жак-Ив Кусто</h1>
            <p class="profile__vocation">Исследователь океана</p> 
</div>

<div class="popup__content">
        <button class="popup__close"></button>
        <h3 class="popup__title">Редактировать профиль</h3>
        <div class="popup__text">
        <input  name="text" placeholder="Укажите Ваше имя" class="popup__text-name" maxlength="35"></input>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Ваша профессия"  class="popup__text-vocation" maxlength="35"></input>
      </div>
        <button class="popup__save">Сохранить</button>
      </div>
```

Нужно, чтобы по нажатию на кнопку "Сохранить", данные из инпута меняли данные в тегах h1 и p.
В целом, я понимаю, что надо вызвать функцию для кнопки сохранить, где выбрать данные инпуты и перенести данные из них в теги, но как это сделать, что-то не доходит.

Суть кода в том, что есть кнопка редактирования данных, по нажатию на неё открывается попап с редактированием данных (это я реализовал), в попапе есть инпуты куда нужно ввести новые данные и по кнопке "сохранить", сохранить новые данные в тегах html.

Comment: "(это я реализовал)" - это *я реализовал* - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336468. Вы меня огорчаете. Вы не смогли догадаться, что надо поменять местами значения слева и справа от знака "равно"?

Comment: Я имел ввиду, само открытие и закрытие попапа. 
Ну у меня сейчас проблема, в непонимании что именно прописывать для функции. Менять местами пробовал, но не вышло, может просто неправильно пробовал

Comment: Я не знаю, что Вы "пробовали". Но больше я Вам писать код не буду, пока не увижу Ваших попыток.

Comment: document.querySelector('.popup__save').onclick = function(){
    textName.value = inputName.value;
    textVocation.value = inputVocation.value; 
}

Как один из вариантов пробовал так, я же правильно понимаю, что если раньше уже прописывали данные для textName, inputName и т.д. по новой не надо все писать в функции?

Comment: Смотря где объявлены эти переменные. Вам что, трудно попробовать объявить их еще раз?

Comment: Объявлены выше функции, но просто даже если объявляю их прямо в функции, это тоже не срабатывает

Comment: Я не знаю, что значит "это не срабатывает".

Comment: document.querySelector('.popup__save').onclick = function(){
    const textName = document.querySelector('.profile__info .profile__name');
const textVocation = document.querySelector('.profile__info .profile__vocation');

const inputName = document.querySelector('.popup__text .popup__text-name');
const inputVocation = document.querySelector('.popup__text .popup__text-vocation');

    textName.value = inputName.value;
    textVocation.value = inputVocation.value; 
}

Прописал такой код, и по нажатию кнопки ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Копировать данные из текстового поля в input](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1336468)

*поменять местами значения слева и справа от знака "равно"*

Comment: Спасибо, изначально не заметил своей ошибки в коде, поправил и всё заработало.